# How to adjust iso time to local time?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm receiving such time for example from the server `2023-09-19T06:15:48` then I convert it to date object:

```
val isoFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
val date = isoFormat.parse(messageModel.isoTime!!)!!
val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
val res = timeFormat.format(date.time)
```

and my resulted time is 2 hours before the real value. I tried to use `TimeZone.getDefault().rawOffset` in such manner:

```
timeFormat.format(TimeZone.getDefault().rawOffset + date.time)
```

when the `date` object is:

```
Tue Sep 19 06:15:48 GMT+02:00 2023
```

but the time difference became 1 hour what is also not ok. Is it possible to do it without adding milliseconds to the received utc long value?

### UPDATE:

Tried to achieve it via:

```
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
Locale.getDefault()
)
dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault() 
dateFormat.parse(date)
```

but it did not help

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what do you try to achieve. Do you mean `2023-09-19T06:15:48` is a UTC time and you need local time with +2:00? What is the correct value for `res` for the above input date time? Is it `08:15`?

Comment: yes, it is right, I have utc 6:15 and my time zone is `Europe` so +2:00 but not really understand how to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest using the new `java.time` API if possible. `java.util.Date` is very old, obsolete and not very convenient to use.

If using new API we can do this with:

```kotlin
LocalDateTime.parse("2023-09-19T06:15:48")
    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))
```

If using old API, we need to specify the timezone when both parsing and formatting:

```kotlin
val isoFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
isoFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val date = isoFormat.parse("2023-09-19T06:15:48")!!
val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
timeFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam")
val res = timeFormat.format(date.time)
```

Comment: yes, thank you, it works, but can I for example replace fixed timezone with `TimeZone.getDefault().id`? is it ok for your solution?

Comment: Yes, if this is what you need then you can use `TimeZone.getDefault()` for the formatting part or even remove the `timeFormat.timeZone = ` line. We have to stick to `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")` for parsing though, because it is fixed at UTC.